# the method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

i am all new to java and android. i was trying to create a simple android app using mysql as backend db. i used the below tutorial link to create one

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

but on the class at bottom i see errors at two places

```
ListView lv = getListView(); and setListAdapter(adapter)
```

the error says the methods are not defined for this type. i couldn't figure out how to resolve it. can anyone please help me here getting out of this. Thanks

```
   AllProductsActivity.java
 package com.example.androidhive;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;   

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // HERE I SEE THE ERROR for not defined for this type
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // HERE I SEE THE ERROR FOR NOT DEFINED
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: you don't need `runOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute`, if you remove that your code will worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setListAdapter(adapter) is in ListActivity not in Asyank Task

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;   

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

 ListAdapter adapter;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products =   "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
     setListAdapter(adapter);

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen , i updated the code like you provided with a little modification of setListAdapter(adapter); to lv.setListAdapter(adapter) to remove the error on it. However it shows error in the post execute block on line adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); with the message that "adapter cannot be resolved"

Comment: had to make below modification in postexecute method                                                 ((BaseAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();                                      to remove error.

Comment: Hey Naveen, i am trying to access a php file saved on my local machine in this app  but i am getting error "connection refused" i given the url in the fashion like "http://my_ip_address/file_location" . However when i put the same url in browser it sends the desired output. can you please help me in this as well ! thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `getListView()`, you will have to instantiate like this -

```
ListView lv = new ListView(YourActivityName.this);
```

or

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
```

if you have declared such listveiw in your xml layout.

Secondly,

Why you are using `runOnUIthread`? `OnPostExecute` anyway runs on UI thread. So this should solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Darpan, thanks for providing the right syntax. i read that adapter must run on UI thread but found out that as of Jelli Bean it is done by OS automatically. i removed the runOnUIthread block.

Answer (score 0):

Donot write runonUiThread(), as the scope is still in Async task, probably you can call another method and put you code into that block.

`onPostExecute(String result){

someOtherMethod(result);

}`

`
private void someOtherMethod(String url){

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                            TAG_NAME},
                                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

}
`